# Linked-lists and deleting nodes through *headRef

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I'm working through some pointer/linked-list problems. One of the problems is to delete all nodes in a list and point the head to NULL.

My solution differs from the given answer. I'm new to this, so I'm having trouble figuring out if and why mine doesn't work. The main problem I'm having is trying to understand what the result of `free(*headRef);` is, and if `*headRef` can share a different pointee after that.

My thinking is: because I have `compliment` point to the next node, I can free `*headRef` which is pointing at the first node (or, more generally, the node before the one compliment is pointing to). Then, I can point `*headRef` to `compliment` and the process can continue.

Here's my code:

```
void DeleteList(struct node** headRef){

    struct node* compliment = *headRef;

    while (compliment != NULL){
            compliment = compliment->next;
            free(*headRef);
            *headRef = compliment;
    }
    *headRef = NULL;
}
```

Assume each node carries two attributes: an int and a `->next` pointer.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: You're in trouble if `headRef` is `NULL`. The `*headRef = NULL;` after the `while` isn't necessary. Otherwise, looks okay.

Comment: @DanielFischer- I would assume that the caller should never be passing a `NULL` pointer into this function.  I'm guessing the intended usage is `DeleteList(&pointerToHeadOfList)`.

Comment: @templatetypedef Correct. I could have thrown in an assert(), I suppose. However, this is an exercise so I admit I cut some corners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that you've posted is fine.  The key step in deleting all nodes is to make sure that you don't try deleting a pointer and then following its `next` pointer.  Since you use the `compliment` pointer to hold the next node on each iteration, what you have looks fine.

As for `free(*headRef)` - this deallocates the pointer pointed at by `headRef`.  Once you've done this, you should be sure not to follow the pointer `*headRef` anymore.  Since you immediately change `*headRef` in the next line to point to the next node in the linked list, you don't have anything to worry about.  The main concern is not to `free` a pointer and then try dereferencing it.  `free`ing a pointer doesn't somehow "poison" the pointer variable and make it bad; instead it destoys the *pointee* and makes that bad.

One detail - the very last line of your function isn't necessary, since when you visit the last node of the linked list and traverse its `next` pointer, you will get `NULL`.  This means that the final iteration of the loop will set `*headRef` to point to `NULL` for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very helpful! I chuckled at the concept of "poisoning" a pointer--it's not far from the mark, though--as I am just starting on pointers and the like, there is a fear of such mystical possibilities. I was most concerned that deallocating the head pointer would be bad for... some unknown reason. But I felt my system was sound. Thanks for the help... and good catch on the setting to NULL!

Answer (score 1):

You could do with less code:

```
void DeleteList(struct node **headRef){

    struct node *tmp;

    while ((tmp = *headref)){
            *headRef = tmp->next
            free(tmp);                
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- you can only get into the loop if there is something to delete at *headref
- inside the loop: tmp cannot be NULL, so it is safe to dereference tmp, so `*headref = tmp->next;` is valid
- after the loop, there is a guarantee that *headref == NULL

Comment: When does this loop terminate? Even at the NULL condition won't it cycle endlessly? I'm not used to seeing declarations as terminating conditions! I would like to understand this.

Comment: No, the `while ((tmp = *headref)){...}` assignment within the condition is a valid loop condition; similar to eg `while (tmp)`. The double parentheses are there to suppress warnings.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. What conditions cause this loop to terminate? It appears to be infinite.

Comment: The `*headRef` is changed (assigned) inside the loop, and will be retested at the next loop-condition-test (remember: an assignment is an expression, too. C is *basically* expression-based; assignments are lower life forms ...).

Comment: Okay, then I'm wondering, what IS the loop condition test? If it is an assignment, it will always be true, no? Like: `while((2 = 2)){` is always true. I guess I don't see how it matters that `*headRef` is being modified, because tmp will be reassigned in `while(())`

Comment: No. Suppose *headRef is not a pointer to pointer, but an ondinary string pointer. Then `while ((ch = *ptr++)) {...}` would be a valid loop, wouldn't it ? A loop condition tests for !zero or !NULL. BTW: `while ((2 =2 )){}` is not valid: 2 is not an assignable lvalue.

Comment: Infinite loops are certainly valid loops, though--I'm not concerned about syntactical correctness. What I would like is to understand why a declaration will **EVER terminate.** Is it not true that `while((NULL = NULL)){` will continue looping? Or `while((x = y)){`, for that matter? (Safer example)

Comment: Again: `while ((NULL = NULL))` is not valid since NULL is not an assignable lvalue. (did you mean: `while((NULL==NULL)){}` , BTW ?) I suggest you reread the C syntax at the back of K&R: it basically says" `while( expr) ...`, and expr can be eiter a constant, or a term (either a single variable *or an assignment* (that is whi `a=b=42;` is valid: `b=42` is also an expression which can be used to *feed* the assignment to a.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22724/discussion-between-d0rmlife-and-wildplasser)

Comment: Okay! For future readers... relevant discussion in K&R 2nd edition is on pg 105-106. Simple answer: assignment to NULL, even when valid, tests to FALSE, so the loop terminates. At least, as I understand it. Also seemed true in a test program I made. +1 for BIZARRE and IMPORTANT syntax. Thanks wildplasser.

Comment: Correction: you cannot assign **to** NULL. You could assigne NULL to a pointer variable (or another assignable lvalue, such as *headref), and the completed assignment would still yield an expression (which could be tested for zero/NULL, as needed by the `while()`) Again: Expressions are the clue.

Comment: That is what I meant, actually. "Assignment to" meaning `*some_pointer = NULL` being `*some_pointer` TO `NULL`. When the `while()` loop tests that condition, it will be false. So it seems.

Comment: It appears you got it. Good luck.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22818/discussion-between-wildplasser-and-d0rmlife)